# Bingo game - how to click/show picks

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, post

I'm trying to create a bingo game with HTML,CSS & PHP (no Javascript). It is intended that a user can play bingo against the computer. The user must be able to indicate the number in the table. But I do not know exactly how to work this out in practice.

This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>bingo</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if (empty($_POST)) {

    $players = array('computer', 'opponent');
    $picks = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i < 16; $i++) 
    {
        $numbers['B'][] = $i;
        $numbers['I'][] = $i+15;
        $numbers['N'][] = $i+30;
        $numbers['G'][] = $i+45;
        $numbers['O'][] = $i+60;
    }

    $letters = array ('B','I','N','G','O');
    foreach ($letters as $letter) {

        foreach($players as $player)
        {
            shuffle($numbers[$letter]);

            $chunks = array_chunk($numbers[$letter], 5);
            $cards[$player][$letter] = $chunks[0];

            if ($letter == 'N') {
                $cards[$player][$letter][2] = ' * '; // *
            }
        } 
    }

    $cardsstr = serialize($cards);
    $picksstr = serialize($picks);

}
else
{

}

?>


Getrokken nummers : <?php echo implode(',', $picks) ?>


<form method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='cardsstr' value='<?php echo $cardsstr ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='ballsstr' value='<?php echo $ballsstr ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='picksstr' value='<?php echo $picksstr ?>' />
<input type='submit' name='cards' value='next number' />
</form>
<a href="bingo2_niels.php">Start Over</a>

<?php

foreach ($cards as $key => $value) 
{
    // Show player
    echo "<h2>" . $key . "</h2>";

    // Start table
    echo "<table border='1'>";

    echo "<tr><td>B</td><td>I</td><td>N</td><td>G</td><td>O</td></tr>";

    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>" . $value['B'][$i] . "</td>
                <td>" . $value['I'][$i] . "</td>
                <td>" . $value['N'][$i] . "</td>
                <td>" . $value['G'][$i] . "</td>
                <td>" . $value['O'][$i] . "</td>
            </tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

But now I'm struggling with the idea how to choose numbers in the table and show when they are selected. Can you help me?

Comment: Seems to me that in 'proper' Bingo, the user can select any number, and only when they hit the Bingo button (or crossed off the last number), you will validate if they indeed selected the right numbers. So I'd start with that: just let them click to toggle the selection. Since you have roundtrips and use PHP, I think you can make this work as a normal HTML form, where each cell is a checkbox. You can make a `<label>` for the checkbox, let that fill out the cell, and hide the checkbox itself. That way, you can make it look like this, with just common form controls and a bit of CSS.

Comment: The next step would be the validation, but if you start with this form input, I think the ideas will grow in your own head how to implement it further. As it is written now, your question is very broad, and will either receive no answers at all, or a complete implementation of your project, which I guess is not your goal either.